# Display list values in another cell/ Cycle through list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of values in cells A1:A75, and a button to randomly select one and display it in cell D3:

```
Sub BingoGen()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim stRow As Long, endRow As Long, dataCol As Long
Dim dispRow As Long, dispCol As Long

Set ws = Sheets("BingoHome")
stRow = 2
dataCol = 1
dispRow = 3
dispCol = 4

    With ws
        endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, dataCol).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(dispRow, dispCol).Value = _
          .Cells(Application.RandBetween(stRow, endRow), dataCol).Value
    End With
```

I would like to alter this to begin by showing the value in A1 and work down the list with each button click.

I have another macro button that will randomize this list of values.

Comment: Use Application.Match to return the row in column A where it matches on what is currently in the output cell then add 1 and return the value in that row.  If it is blank return A1.

Comment: @ScottCraner what would the syntax for this be? At the moment I have: ```.Cells(Application.Match((stRow, endRow)+1), dataCol).Value```

Comment: `.Cells(Application.Match(.Range("D3"),.Range("A:A"),0)+1, dataCol).Value`

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a **static** variable to store the location the presently referenced cell.

```
Sub BingoGen()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim stRow As Long, endRow As Long, dataCol As Long
    Dim dispRow As Long, dispCol As Long
    Static dataRow As Integer

    Set ws = Sheets("BingoHome")
    stRow = 2
    dataCol = 1
    dispRow = 3
    dispCol = 4
    With ws
        'if you will always have 75 rows I would just use endRow = 75
        endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, dataCol).End(xlUp).Row
        'if the data row is undefined or larger than the end row
        If dataRow < 1 Or dataRow > endRow Then
            dataRow = 1
        'otherwise (1<= dataRow <= endRow) index dataRow by 1
        Else
            dataRow = dataRow + 1
        End If
        .Cells(dispRow, dispCol).Value = .Cells(dataRow, dataCol).Value
    End With
```

Also, out of curiosity is there a reason that you are typing all of your variables as `Long`, when they would easily fit in an `Integer`?